# проблема с версткой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Нужно расположить картинки слева от `li`

Вот код [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```
<div class="left">
    <h1>Product name</h1>
    <ul>
         <img src="img/check-icon.png" alt="#"><li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
         <img src="img/check-icon.png" alt="#"><li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
         <img src="img/check-icon.png" alt="#"><li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
         <img src="img/check-icon.png" alt="#"><li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Вот код [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
ul li {

    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[image: Вот так должно все выглядеть]

Comment: внутри ul - прямым потомком может быть только li.

Comment: хорошо, а как мне вставить картинку тогда? Мне не помогает `ul li:before`

Comment: вам ответ уже дали. С помощью псевдоэлемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант через `background` для `li`

Пример

```css
body{
    background: #333;
}
ul{
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;    
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Yes_Check_Circle.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
    <li>Put on this page information about your product Put on this page information about your product</li>
    <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
    <li>Put on this page information about your product</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите картинки из html и вставьте их в css:

```
ul li:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 20px; /* ширина картинки */
  height: 15px; /* высота картинки */
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: url(img/check-icon.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял. Я вставил код, но ничего не заработало. Я не понимаю как указать, что оно должно быть именно перед этими li.

Comment: оно не перед li должно быть, а внутри него. я вам описал логику, без воспроизводимого примера воспроизводимый ответ дать не могу

Comment: `ul li:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url(img/check-icon.png);
}` можете объяснить эту логику. каким образом вставить это в li?

Comment: это вставляется в css, и создает внутри li псевдоэлемент, в котором фон - ваша галочка